# Is glTexStorage2D imperative when auto generating mipmaps

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I do update to a texture2D in OpenGL 4.0 using gltexSubImage2D().The texture has mipmaps auto generated using

```
 glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

My texture update was failing till I understood I had to regenerate mipmaps on update too (or remove mipmaps generation).Then I read [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Automatic_mipmap_generation) wiki where there is a usage of [glTexStorage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexStorage2D.xml) when generating mipmaps.I actually never paid attention to this method.So I wonder if  I have to use it every time I generate a texture with mipmaps?

Update :

I see from the method specs that it

> specifies the storage requirements for all levels
>               of a two-dimensional texture or one-dimensional texture array simultaneously

I guess using it should improve the performance when generating mipmaps?Is it true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before there was glTexStorage, each mipmap level had to be initialized by a separate call to glTexImage. glTexImage triggers a lot of complex internal state changes, which are rather expensive. Every time glTexImage is called, the layout of the texture object is altered.

Hence you try to avoid using it, if possible. As you discovered, you must first initialize all desired mipmap levels before you can update them by glTexSubImage. glGenerateMipmap will create them, which introduce layout changes, which is, yes, expensive.

glTexStorage initializes the whole texture object once for a desired, immutable format. Yes, using glTexStorage improves performance when used together wigh glGenerateMipmap or data updates by glTexSubImage, but the improvements happen very early at texture object creation, and not so much when its data is changed.

Comment: Ok , but does it mean ,if I use glTexStorage , I won't need to call glGenerateMipmap every time I update the texture ?

Comment: @MichaelIV: "The two functions are completely orthogonal."

Comment: @MichaelIV: What Nicol Bolas means by this is, that they can't be replaced by each other.

Comment: I understood that if I have no problem with immutable mipmaps  then I should use glTexStorage.Also  If you look into the "Common mistakes" link I provided you can see that in texture creation demo ,where glTexStorage is used ,the author uses gltexsubimage straight away.Why? Also ,I don't get it ,why I have to re-generate mipmaps again when I update my textures.

Comment: @MichaelIV: See, you didn't understand it: Immutable format-layout does not mean immutable data. What glTexStorage makes immutable is the format-layout of the texture, i.e. its dimensions, internal data type and format and range of mipmap levels. But the data itself can be altered (mutated) at any time.

Answer (score 31):

The two functions are completely orthogonal.

The choice is between `glTexImage2D` and `glTexStorage2D`. Both of these [allocate storage for texture images](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage); they just do it in different ways.

`glTexImage2D` is the old way of allocating storage. It [creates mutable storage (there are other functions that create mutable storage too)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage). If you want mipmaps, you have to allocate each mipmap level with a separate call to the function, manually computing the size of the mipmap image (see below for the exception to this).

`glTexStorage2D` allocates [immutable storage for the image data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Immutable_storage). It allocates all of the mipmaps you want all at once.

Immutable storage, as the name suggests, cannot be changed. See, you can call `glTexImage2D` on the same mipmap level, with a different size. And if you do, OpenGL will destroy the original mipmap level and allocate storage for the new one. You can even change formats.

Immutable storage won't let you change any of that. You can [upload new data, using functions like `glTexSubImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Storage_contents). But those functions don't change the *storage*; they change the contents.

`glTexImage2D` and `glTexStorage2D` are like `malloc`. `glTexSubImage2D` is like `memcpy`; it only works for *existing* memory.

`glGenerateMipmap` is a function that will take the base layer of a texture and [generate the data for all of the mipmaps from that base layer (given the mipmap range)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Automatic_mipmap_generation). It does this *one time*. Think of it like a rendering function; it does its job and then it's done.

For mutable storage textures, `glGenerateMipmap` will also allocate storage for any mipmaps in the mipmap range that were not previously allocated. That's why you can call `glTexImage2D` once, then call `glGenerateMipmap` to force it to make all of the other mipmaps without having to do it manually.